# Drupal 7 - Programmatically tagging nodes

Tags: php, drupal, tags, taxonomy

I am trying to populate the content of a Drupal 7 site programatically by reading from a CSV file. I have all the code for that, but the next step is to automatically tag each node with a series of terms found in 3 different columns.

Now I know that I can tag the node using the term id, but is there a way to tag using the term name?

I'm looking  at something like this where $tags is an array of strings that are supposed to be tag terms.

```
$a = 0;
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  $node->field_tags[$node->language][]['a'] = $tag;
  $a++;
}
```

I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of finding the term ids yourself, you can use [taxonomy_get_term_by_name](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7) function.

This function returns the list of matching term objects.

Comment: How would I use those term objects to set the tags of the new node? Also, will this create the taxonomy objects for terms that don't exist yet?

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work. I get errors:

    `foreach ($tags as $tag) {
 $tid = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($tag);
 $node->field_tags[$node->language][]['tid'] = $tid;
    }`

Comment: taxonomy_get_term_by_name returns an array of matching term OBJECTS, not just a single tid.  Read the documentation here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7

Comment: @ErikAhlswede If I pass the exact name of the taxonomy term does it return an array of size 1?